# Spring cloud stream with rabbitmq single consumer out of pool of autoscaled pool of consumer instances

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, autoscaling

I have a system with several microsystems, using Spring Cloud Streams (Spring Boot 2.7.5) and RabbitMQ for messaging between the systems. We have a problem where the receiver of the message is run for every instance of the microservice we have running. Is there some way to limit the message to only one instance of this service. The flow is as follows:

1. User submits some information, along with their email address
2. System receives information, stores it, and publishes a message on RabbitMQ that the information is submitted
3. All (3) of the running consumers receive the message, and send an email to the user that the information is received. There should only be one email sent.

The message is published like this:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class IssueEventPublisherImpl implements IssueEventPublisher {

    private final StreamBridge publisher;

    @Override
    public void dispatch(IssueSubmitted issueSubmitted) {
        publisher.send("issue-submitted-events", issueSubmitted);
    }
}
```

And received like this:

```
@Bean
public Consumer<IssueSubmitted> issueSubmittedEventConsumer(EmailSendingLogic sendEmail) {
    return event -> sendEmail(...);
}
```

With this configuration:

```
# Rabbit MQ
spring.rabbitmq.host=${RABBITMQ_HOST:localhost}
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=${RABBITMQ_CLIENT_USERNAME:guest}
spring.rabbitmq.password=${RABBITMQ_CLIENT_PASSWORD:guest}

spring.cloud.function.definition=issueSubmittedEventConsumer
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.issueSubmittedEventConsumer-in-0.destination=issue-submitted-events
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.issueSubmittedEventConsumer-in-0.group=some-named-group
```

Is there some additional configuration we can use to limit the amount of recipients of this message to 1, no matter how many instances of the Consumer Spring Application we start?

I have already tried to add the group, which did nothing. Having a separate group-name for each service would also not accomplish much, I'd think. Googling this issue has not been very helpful, since most people seem to want the opposite, where a consumer want to listen to multiple queues, or should receive all messages. And none of the tutorials mention a cloud environment with autoscaling.

Answer (score 0):

The message was sent and received by the same system, which for some reason still unknown to me caused it to be picked up for every running instance. We ended up using Springs internal messaging bus: `ApplicationEventPublisher` instead of the `StreamBridge`, which worked fine.